# Solving Boolean expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

(A+C+D)(A+C+D’)(A+C’+D)(A+B’)
This is my first attempt on solving four algebraic terms using boolean expression. I am stuck,please help me. I have a test tommorow.

Thanks!

Comment: May be you should simplify this?

Comment: You can *solve an equation* but you cannot *solve an expression*.  Do you mean *simplify an expression*?

Comment: Tell us what you know.  Do you know what a Karnaugh map is?  Do you know how to simplify $(X+Y)(X+Y')$?

Comment: Why was the tag [tag:boolean-algebra] removed?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche From the tag description: Boolean algebras are structures which behave similar to a power set with complement, intersection and union. Questions regarding Boolean algebras as structures, or regarding functions defined from/to Boolean algebras fit into this tag very nicely. For Boolean logic use the tag propositional logic

Comment: I am suppose to solve the given boolean function to a minimum literal.

Comment: @wythagoras, ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I assume that '+' is for '$\vee$'**

Look at first two terms, and let $A+C=T$:
$$
(A+C+D)(A+C+D') = (T+D)(T+D') = TT+DT+TD'+DD' = T(T+D+D')+DD' = T(T+1)+DD' = T = A + C.
$$
Ok, let's simplify $(A+C)(A+C' + D)$:
$$
(A+C)(A+C' + D) = (C+A)(C' + (A + D)) = CC' + AC' + C(A+D) + A(A+D) = AC' + C(A+D) + A = (A + AC') + C(A+D) = A + CA + CD = A + CD.
$$
And last part,
$$
(A+CD)(A+B') = A + CDA + AB' + B'CD = A + B'CD
$$
It's just an algebra with some specific rules. Good luck on test!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Simplify bracket by bracket. For example $$(A+C+D)(A+C+D') = AA+AC+AD'+CA+CC+CD'+DA+DC+DD' \\ = A+AC+AD'+CA+C+CD'+DA+DC \\= A+AC+AD'+C+CD'+DA+DC \\= A+AC+C+A(D+D')+C(D+D') \\= A+AC+C+A+C=A+C+AC=A+C$$

Now you can put this expression in the place of the first two brackets and solve again, keeping the rules of simplifying in mind.